# How to block malformed requests to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, block

I'd like to block malformed requests like these:

```
79.26.188.208 - - [05/Apr/2011:13:47:38 +0200] "\xae\xe1\x0fi\xca\xeba\xdfm\x9d\xb5\xc0yr-n\x05Z\x9f\xa7\x05\xa1g" 200 4855 "-" "-"
82.51.130.83 - - [05/Apr/2011:18:25:38 +0200] "T\xd0\xc55\xc3A\xcd\xd0" 200 4855 "-" "-"
```

What is the preferred method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Mikel's lead I added this mod_security rule

```
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^(?:GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|POST|CONNECT)$"
```

and now only legitimate requests pass through.

Answer (score 1):

[mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) is useful for blocking many of these requests.

It detects known exploit patterns and blocks them.

Comment: @Mikel: I'm already using mod_security, but what should I filter for? Requests without GET/POST?

Comment: This is not necessarily a known exploit pattern. Some googling shows that these requests can come from legitimate sources. To see why Apache is printing these characters in the logfile, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#format-notes

Comment: @Stefan Lasiewski: I see, but those requests are making my CMS (Silverstripe) throw tons of warnings, so I'd like to block them out :)

Comment: @Joril: Actually, we are using Silverstripe as well, and I haven't noticed that sort of request yet (We have a very effective IDS, and we get attacked constantly, so the IDS might be blocking the bad IPs after a few requests). Let me look and see if we are actually getting those requests.

Comment: @Joril: It does seem that requests without a method (GET, POST, HEAD, etc.) are certainly malformed, and should probably be blocked. I wonder if those are coming from a bad client. I'm confused why Apache is logging those requests in access_log at all-- aren't those errors?

Comment: @Stefan Lasiewski: well if I telnet into the server and issue some meaningless command such as `qwert` I get a 400 error.. Maybe the "exploiting" script does something stranger :/

Comment: Anyway I added this rule: `SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "!^(?:GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|POST|CONNECT)$"` and it looks like it's working :)